# Strings in Delphi: Pre-allocate memory to increase performance in simple cases?

Tags: delphi, optimization, delphi-xe2, string-concatenation

I'm one of those so-called developers who got their way with Delphi without really understanding or even thinking about basics. In this case, I'm talking about **strings**.

While I do understand how **pre-allocating memory** can result in a significant speed gain. I don't understand how to use it in simple, real-world, cases (this is even more true with the TStringBuilder).

For example, let's say I have this code that recursively search a folder & add results to a hash list:

```
var
   FilesList : TDictionary<String, Byte>;  // Byte = (file = 0, folder = 1)

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ //
procedure AddFolder(const AFolderName : String);
var
   FileName : String;
   AHandle  : THandle;
   FindData : TWin32FindData;
begin
     AHandle := FindFirstFile(PChar(AFolderName + '*'), FindData);
     if (AHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
        Exit;

     repeat
           if (FindData.dwFileAttributes And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0) then
           begin
                { Add a file. }
                FileName := FindData.cFileName;
                FilesList.Add(AFolderName + FileName, 0);
           end
           else if ((FindData.cFileName[0] <> '.') OR Not ((FindData.cFileName[1] = #0) OR (FindData.cFileName[1] = '.') And (FindData.cFileName[2] = #0))) then
           begin
                FileName := AFolderName + FindData.cFileName + '\';
                FilesList.Add(FileName, 1);
                AddFolder(FileName);
           end;
     until Not FindNextFile(AHandle, FindData);

     Windows.FindClose(AHandle);
end;
```

I'm not sure if it's a good example, but in this case, it's not clear to me how pre-allocating memory to the variable `FileName` would help increase the execution speed, especially that I know nothing about its length. **Assuming this is possible, how?**

Or **is the pre-allocation technique only useful when concatenating / building strings?**

---

**Notes about my question:**

1. The question is primarily for **XE2**, but feel free to reference other delphi versions as I'm sure other developers will benefit from sharing the wisdom (that is, assuming mods won't delete it as chatty or subjective)
2. I'm more interested in **simple everyday cases** where one needs to **make micro-optimization in very large loops / with huge amount of data** by optimizing string memory pre-allocation.

Comment: As 500-Internal Server Error states, most of the problem with strings comes in the fact that the compiler always wants to create new memory, copy the string with new data, then free the old memory.  The Delphi versions that started incorporating FastMM do a little better with this, but anytime you can stay away from strings in a time-intensive process, it's a good thing.  In short, your sample code probably wouldn't benefit from any tricks.  If you are interested in performance, always profile your app to find out where your program is spending its execution time.

Comment: @Glenn1234 +1 for "If you are interested in performance, always profile your app to find out where your program is spending its execution time."

Comment: I'm afraid you guys are missing my point, I **did** use my profiler and I know full well where are the weak points in my application (and still discovering), I was/am trying to see if there's room for improvements as far as strings allocation is concerned (generally speaking, not just for the sample code I posted), hope this clarify my intention

Comment: You say that you used the profiler to identify the bottleneck. But I personally would be surprised if the time spent in the Delphi string RTL units consumed more than 2 orders of magnitude less time than is spent calling `FindNextFile`. When you profiled this code, what did the break down look like?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Indeed and I'm not debating that, but having to insist over and over that the question is about **learning about strings** rather than optimizing with the profiler is beyond me!

Comment: @thedude in the case that you posted, likely not.  The only time when you need to watch string use is if you are doing a whole lot more than what you are in the sample code.  For example, I'm working on optimizing a base64 implementation right now, and I found rather quickly that directly using strings is incredibly bad news if I want it to be fast.   Like DavidHeffernan states, though, FindNextFile is likely the predominant part and you can't do anything about that.

Comment: But you do know the length of `FileName` before you assign to it. It's the sum of the lengths of the strings that you are concatenating. But the RTL already takes advantage of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you got away without understanding how Strings really work: Delphi is grate in that respect, it's string manipulation is highly effective and it's memory-manager is also highly-effective for small memory blocks. You can do ALOT with Delphi and not have a problem with String manipulation.

There are some classes of problems where you should take care, especially if the routines you're looking at are to be reused (library code).

For example, this should *always* raise a flag:

```
Result := '';
for i:=1 to N do
  Result := Result + Something; // <- Recursively builds the string, one-char-at-a-time
```

Even THAT might fly with Delphi, if it's not often use or is used where time is not critical. None the less that kind of code should be optimized so the entire (likely) length of the string is pre-allocated, then trimmed in then end:

```
SetLength(Result, Whatever);
for i:=1 to N do
  Result[i] := SomeChar;
SetLength(Result, INowKnowTheLength);
```

Now for an example where the `TStringBuilder` shines. If you have something like this:

```
var Msg: string;
begin
  Msg := 'Mr ' + MrName + #13#10;
  if SomeCondition then
    Msg := Msg + 'We were unable to reach you'
  else
    Msg := Msg + 'We need to let you know';
  Msg := Msg + #13#10 
end;
```

i.e: code that builds one complex (and possibly large) bit of message, then you can *easily* optimize it using `TStringBuilder`:

```
var Msg: TStringBuilder;
begin
  Msg := TStringBuilder.Create;
  try
    Msg.Append('Mr ');
    Msg.Append(MrName);
    Msg.Append(#13#10);
    if SomeCondition then
      Msg.Append('We were unable to reach you')
    else
      Msg.Append('We need to let you know');
    Msg.Append(#13#10);
    ShowMessage(Msg.ToString); // <- Gets the whole string
  finally Msg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Any way, always balance the ease of writing, ease of maintenance with the true benefits of the performance. Don't exceed natural limits for the code your write: optimizing a string-generating routine to be faster then the HDD can write is wasted effort. Optimizing some GUI code to generate a message in 1ms (instead of 20ms) is also wasted effort - the user would never know your code was 20 times faster, it'd be just as instantaneous.

Answer (score 9):

Straight up string concatenation (for example) can be slow because the memory for the string is reallocated for each piece that is appended. Sometimes the new size can actually be accommodated in place but sometimes the data must be copied to a new location, the old buffer freed, and so on. This takes time.

In general, though, this should be of no concern to you unless you have verified with a performance profiler or explicit timing statements that you do in fact have a performance issue.

Comment: Yes I know that, I believe [this clarifies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207000/strings-in-delphi-pre-allocate-memory-to-increase-performance-in-simple-cases#comment19707738_14207000) my question. I guess I was trying to improve something that can't be improved...

Answer (score 3):

Basically it is these concatenations you are talking about:

```
AFolderName + '*'
AFolderName + FindData.cFileName
AFolderName + FindData.cFileName + '\'
```

The first one is done once, the loop executes either the second and third.

These methods in System.pas are used internally for the 3 lines:

```
procedure _UStrCat3(var Dest: UnicodeString; const Source1, Source2: UnicodeString);
procedure _UStrCat3(var Dest: UnicodeString; const Source1, Source2: UnicodeString);
procedure _UStrCatN(var Dest: UnicodeString; ArgCnt: Integer; const Strs: UnicodeString); varargs;
```

Since the 3 values are different, you cannot optimize it using only one expression.

All functions precalculate the final length and do the proper allocation work if needed.

Inside the loop, you might try to do the preallocation of the `AFolderName + FindData.cFileName + '\'` yourself, and snap out the `AFolderName + FindData.cFileName` portion, but then you require 2 allocations for the `then` case.

So I think your code cannot get optimized much further (i.e. you cannot get it to perform an order of magnitude better).